# How can I read text appended to the end of a file I already read?

Tags: java, text, io

I want to read a text file in Java. After I finish, some text will be appended by another application, and then I want to read that. Lets say there are ten lines. When the other app appends one more line, I dont want to read the whole file again; just the new line. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this could work:

```
BufferedReader reader = .. // create a reader on the input file without locking it
while(otherAppWritesToFile) {
  String line = reader.readLine();
  while(line != null) {
    processLine(line);
    line = reader.readLine();
  }
  Thread.sleep(100);
}
```

Exception handling has been left out for the sake of simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

Once you get an EOF indication, wait a little bit and then try reading again.

**Edit:** Here is teh codez to support this solution. You can try it and then change the control flow mechanisms as needed.

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
    final Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    final BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"));

    boolean cont = true;
    while (cont) {
        String line = input.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            line = input.readLine();
        }
        System.out.println("EOF reached, add more input and type 'y' to continue.");
        final String in = keyboard.nextLine();
        cont = in.equalsIgnoreCase("y");

    }
}
```

EDIT: Thanks for adding some code Tim. Personally, I would just do a sleep instead of waiting for user input. That would more closely match the users' requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a RandomAccessFile.

Open the file and then invoke the length() to get the length of the file. Then you can use the readLine() method to get your data. Then the next time you open the file you can use the seek() method to position yourself to the previous end of the file. Then read the lines and save the new length of the file.